# Add default alert for every user on list

Tags: alert

I have a list and I would like to set an alert for "Item created by me is modified".

I would like to, by default, have set this alert for every user in the company.

I know I can create a workflow that runs on when an item is edited, but I would prefer to use the out of the box alerts if possible.

Is there a clean easy global way to do this?

Do I need to set an event reciever for item added and set an alert on the item level?

Answer (score 1):

taken from http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/forums/t/2201.aspx

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://intranet.sharepoint.com"
$group = $web.Groups["Intranet Members"]
$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]
foreach ($user in $group.Users){
     $alert = $user.Alerts.Add()
     $alert.Title = "My Alert"
     $alert.AlertType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertType]::List
     $alert.List = $list
     $alert.DeliveryChannels = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertDeliveryChannels]::Email
     $alert.EventType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventType]::Add
     $alert.AlertFrequency = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAlertFrequency]::Immediate
     $alert.Update()
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Is there a way to have this maintainable for future users getting added to the site?

Comment: You may create a dummy user which has his email set to a distribution group for all users and add the alert to this user.